# What is the difference between Cubit and Equatable?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Why we should use cubit ?

When to use Equatable ?

what is the diffrence between **Cubit** and **Equatable**?

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Cubit method-based state is a structure that you can update, while bloc works entirely with streams. You should also send an event(async) to update the state in Bloc.

The Equatable library, on the other hand, is used to ensure that your screen is not refreshed again if the state is the same as the previous state when updated. There is an increase in performance because the screen is not refreshed again and again unnecessarily. The Equatable package generates hashes according to the parameters you add in the background.